Texture is appearing transparent
I'm attempting to use UV mapping to apply a texture onto this mesh, and the UV mapping seems to be working perfectly fine, but the texture is appearing transparent. The transparency disappears when I pull the map off of the texture I'm trying to apply.



I've tried of few different solutions I found online including making sure backface culling wasn't enabled and use nodes was enabled but with no luck. Any help is appreciated <3 Thanks in advance


You are in Solid shading mode and in the Options you have set Color to Texture.

Now the problem here is, Solid mode is not Material Preview: it does not show you how the complete material would look like, therefore you would have to either choose the mentioned Material Preview or Rendered mode.
Texture is not equal to material. Of course if a material is basically just one single texture on a surface it mostly looks like it, but the texture is only a part of the shader. The Color option Texture does what it says, it shows you the texture. And since a material can have more than one texture (for example like the one in question which has two), it only shows the active texture which is or was selected in the material. Even after selecting other nodes, as long as they are no texture nodes the viewport will show the last selected image texture.
And in your case this is the image named "BaseTexture" which is transparent in the top area (I've untangled this "blob" of nodes in the shader):

As soon as you select the other image "DiffuseMap", the hair is no longer transparent:

The Texture option does not take the Principled BSDF or the Mix Shader into account, it only shows a single selected texture. Image Texture to be precise, it also does not show procedural textures like Noise, Voronoi etc.
But this is the Solid mode. If you would switch to Material Preview for example, the hair will not be transparent, no matter which image texture you have selected because it shows the complete shader, not just a texture.

I have a more detailed explanation of how the Texture option works in Solid mode and what the other options there mean in my answer to this question Can not display a single mesh as solid, if you are interested in learning more about what you can do with the Color options in Solid mode.
